# Check for null in == override

Tags: c#

In the following C# snippet I override the `==` method. `_type` is a number of type `short`. So I'm actually saying that two `WorkUnitType`s are the same when those two `short`s are the same.

```
public static bool operator ==(WorkUnitType type1, WorkUnitType type2)
{
    if (type1 == null || type2 == null)
        return false;
    return type1._type == type2._type;
}
```

Because R# warns me, and it is totally clear why, that `type1`/`type2` could potentially be null I'm trying to catch that with the `if` statement above.

Now I'm getting a `StackOverflowException` which makes totally sense because I'm actually calling the override.

**Question:** How do I write this method "correct". How can I catch the case that `type1` or `type2` can be `null`?

**My best guess:** Maybe I'm just misusing `==` here and checking for equality should be done with the `Equals` override. But still I think the problem exists. So where is my error in reasoning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the `ReferenceEquals()` function, which will compare directly, bypassing your operator overload.

Comment: I didn't know that `ReferenceEquals` exists. This is actually the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what SLaks said, you likely also want to return true if both are equal to null.  So, like this:

```
public static bool operator ==(WorkUnitType type1, WorkUnitType type2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(type1, null))
        return ReferenceEquals(type2, null);

    if (ReferenceEquals(type2, null))
        return false;

    return type1._type == type2._type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake: you can also cast the two arguments to `object`. This will use the implementation as defined in `object` and not your custom one.

In code:

```
if ((object) type1 == null || (object) type2 == null)
```